# Docker muito lento no Windows 10

Tags: windows, cmd, docker, powershell

Recentemente instalei o Docker for Windows no meu notebook, entretanto está muito lento.

Possuo um notebook DELL Latitude 7490 com 8gb RAM, 240gb SSD e processador intel I5 8° geração - Windows 10 Enterprise.

O Hyper-V está funcionando o virtualizador também.

Tentei rodar o comando "docker version" tanto no CMD quanto no PowerShell demorou o mesmo tempo em ambos. Aproximadamente 50 seg.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

infelizmente o Docker no Windows não é tão bom, pois ele tem que emular uma maquina linux pra servir o kernel para as imagens e so depois usar o conceito de contêiner e pilhas, e outra coisa que eu reparei é que em especial o Windows 10 recentemente esta mais lento que o normal para Docker, digo isso porque já uso Docker a mais de 3 anos, como o Docker para windows é relativamente novo e windows 10 está com vários relatos de problemas acredito que você vai ter muita dificuldade mesmo nessa plataforma, pelome nos por um tempo, pelo que eu estou vendo da microsoft ela esta se atualizando rápido e quem sabe eles mudam isso.

Mas resumindo referente a desempenho não tem muito que se fazer, nesse link foi aberto uma discussão para ajudar as pessoas com esse problema e os desenvolvedores conseguir ajudar, espero que seja útil

https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1936